# "Will damage your computer. You should move it to the Trash" by my own app

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

Today my Mac showed error message above for my own compiled app. This app worked for years. I slightly changed something, but what's the reason for this? How can I avoid it? There is no danger!
I'm using Xcode 10.15 and OSX 10.15.5.
It runs under XCode, but not standalone.

Comment: You did not read my information! I did not install anything, I used my compiled app. And it depends on programming, but I found the solution. I will write it to my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason/solution.
XCode may had a problem. **I copied all files to another folder** and restarted XCode with that new location. After compilation everything worked fine (as before).
Seems to be an internal problem of caches of XCode.

Comment: That message generally means there's something wrong with the code signature on the app (e.g. the signature doesn't match the app's actual contents). Maybe XCode was somehow generating incorrect signatures?

Comment: Maybe, I couldn't retry it. ;-) And I won't! :-)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Use `sign to run locall` could fix this issue for me.